# Согласование с числительными на "один"

Tags: согласование, числительные

Какое правильное согласование в предложении вроде этого:

Он взял камушки, ...

- те самые двадцать один камушек.
- тот самый двадцать один камушек.

Или же как-то по-другому?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это непростой вопрос.

Можно сказать и "тот самый двадцать один камушек", и "те самые двадцать один камушек". Второе предпочтительнее. Дело в том, что сочетание существительного с числительным (количество чего-либо) воспринимается как единое целое и таким образом приобретает множественное число при согласовании. Это не императивно, иное тоже не будет ошибкой, но это будет стилистическое подчеркивание ***числа*** составляющих, а не их единого целого. Поэтому ваш первый вариант - основной.

Есть еще несколько факторов, влияющих на выбор варианта: например, идет ли определение до количественного сочетания или после, является ли существительное мерой (единицей измерения) и проч. Но это не столь важно. Подробнее о грамматике сочетаний числительного и существительного можно посмотреть у Розенталя или в "Академической грамматике", и там и там - несколько объемных параграфов.