# Правописание числительных в документах

Tags: грамматика, единственное-множественное-число, количественно-именное-сочетание

Подскажите правильно ли следующее: "...внедрено **двадцать одно рационализаторское предложение**, направленное ..."?

Comment: Наверно, лучше разбить на две фразы. "...внедрено двадцать одно рационализаторское предложение. Все они направлены..."


Или уж: "...направленные ..."

Comment: Для редактирования  нужен полный текст этого предложения.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [Согласование с числительными на “один”](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424849/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd)

Answer (score 1):

Лучше бы предложение перестроить, чтобы проблему ед./мн. ч. обойти. Но если выбора нет, то я бы написал так:

**Внедрены двадцать одно рационализаторское предложение, направленные на...**

Думаю, причастный оборот не может стоять в ед. ч., когда говорится о множестве объектов, а поэтому придется и сказуемое поставить во мн. ч. Подобное разрешено. (*Двадцать один делегат встретились за круглым столом; Двадцать один ящик с посудой, которые были доставлены на базу, попали туда по ошибке*). Вот что пишет Розенталь ([§184. Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте)](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_02)):

> При составных числительных, оканчивающихся на один, сказуемое, как правило, ставится в форме единственного числа, например: Двадцать один делегат прибыл на совещание; ...было подано сразу тридцать одно заявление (Шолохов). Форма множественного числа данной конструкции может быть обусловлена контекстом, например: Двадцать один делегат встретились за круглым столом (сказуемое-глагол встретились указывает на взаимное действие, которое выражается формой множественного числа); Двадцать один ящик с посудой, которые были доставлены на базу, попали туда по ошибке (влияние придаточного предложения с союзным словом которые в форме множественного числа); За все уплачено 231 рубль (при формальной роли подлежащего счетный оборот имеет значение обстоятельства меры в страдательной конструкции); Двадцать один студент не явились на экзамен (эмоционально окрашенный разговорный вариант, подчеркивающий количество отсутствовавших).